# change the linear value of gradient hr

Tags: asp.net, css, linear-gradients

I have a CSS code that change the `<hr/>` to gradient type ,

```
<hr class="style-one" />
```

.....

```
hr.style-one
{
border: 0;
height: 1px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

But the style generate ( white - black -white ) gradient , you can check it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcHRg/) :)
How can I change this gradient to ( black - white ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to

```
hr.style-one
{
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Follow [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mcHRg/3/)